# while transferring some data from MySQL database table to a downloadable excel file using PHP , some blank rows appearing at the top in excel file

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export

I am transferring some data from MySQL database table to a downloadable excel file using PHP.

It is a simple code. However, in the Excel file, there are always first 2 rows, and the 3rd row's first 8 cells (I am retrieving 8 fields from Database table) are appearing blank.

Then actual data of first table record are appearing.

From 4th row onwards the data is perfectly displayed, with no blank cells. I am unable to find out my error. I request you to please have a look at my code, shown below:

```
    function filterData(&$val,$key){ 
      $val = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $val); 
      $val = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $val); 
      if(strstr($val, '"')) $val = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $val) . '"'; 
    } 

    $fileName = "transFile.xlsx" ;

    $dbObj = new dbConnect($servername,$dbname,$username,$password) ;

    $sql = "select srNo,tranDt,chqNo,particulars,dr,cr,bal,sol from transdata " ;
    $ret = $dbObj->query($sql) ;
    $exportStr = "" ;

    if($ret[0]) {
      if ($ret[1]->num_rows > 0) {
        $flag = true ;

        while ($row = $ret[1]->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            if ($flag){
               $titles = array_keys($row) ;
               array_walk($titles, 'filterData');
               $exportStr .= implode("\t",array_values($titles)) . "\n" ;   
               $flag = false ;
            }
                    
            array_walk($row, 'filterData');
            $exportStr .= implode("\t",array_values($row)) . "\n" ;
        }
      }
      else {
        $exportStr = "No data found" ;
      }
    }

    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='" . $fileName . "'"); 
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0");

    echo $exportStr ;
    exit ;
```

This is the outcome of the code:

An Excel file is created which can be downloaded as is intended . However the first 2 rows and first 8 cells in the 3rd row are appearing blank in the excel file.

I am retrieving 8 fields from Database Table.

The first records from the database table data are appearing in the 3rd row from the 9th cell onwards.

From the 4th row onwards the data is displayed properly.

I tried to do hard coding on the field names of the database table instead of retrieving it from database but it did not work.

I am listing here some sample source data from database for better understanding of the issue .

```
|------
```

|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**rowId**//|int|No|
|srNo|int|Yes|NULL
|tranDT|date|Yes|NULL
|chqNo|int|Yes|NULL
|particulars|varchar(200)|Yes|NULL
|dr|decimal(10,3)|Yes|NULL
|cr|decimal(10,3)|Yes|NULL
|bal|decimal(10,3)|Yes|NULL
|sol|decimal(10,3)|Yes|NULL
== Dumping data for table transdata

|206|1|2023-01-01|342568759|UPI/P7B/ Kotak nami finserv|600.000|0.000|394617.480|72.000
|207|2|2023-01-01|342568758|UPI/P7B/naf bank/09356|16925.000|0.000|377692.480|2567.000
|208|3|2023-01-01|342568757|0354672900:Int.Pd:01-10-2002 to 31-12-2002|0.000|2305.000|379997.480|72.000
|209|4|2023-02-01|342568756|/NEFT/AXIR456793/HDFC BAN/HDFC BA/credit|61500.000|0.000|318497.480|72.000
|210|5|2023-04-01|342568755|/NEFT/AXIR443266699/PREETI S/IDFC BA/Rent|65650.000|0.000|252847.480|72.000

Thanks
Topoti

Comment: FYI you seem to be actually generating a tab-delimited text file. That is not a true xlsx file

Comment: Please provide some sample source data from the database (as a text table please, not a picture!!), so we can see what the expected output from that data would be. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your `filterData` function that you apply to each row of data, gives you "empty" results ...? This should not have been written this way to begin with - [`fputcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) exists (and can also be used to write directly to the output buffer, instead of a file.)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302472/5947043

Comment: `I am listing here some sample source data from database`...you are storing the data in HTML format in your database??? If not, why did you put html into the sample? I provided you a link which shows how to format a data table in your posts. It does not involve html

Comment: html format !! .. no .